# Selenium WebDriver Java -- Mouse moving to wrong element

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I am automating amazon.com, and I am currently trying to move to a specific element in a drop down menu. No matter how specific I make my xpath for this element, WebDriver will only move the mouse to the first item in the list.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="nav-template nav-flyout-content nav-tpl-itemList">                            
<span class="nav-hasPanel nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="InstantVideoPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Amazon Video">                          
<span class="nav-text">Amazon Video</span>                          
</span>                                             
 <span class="nav-hasPanel nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="DigitalMusicPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Amazon Music">                          
 <span class="nav-text">Amazon Music</span>                          
 </span>                                              
 <span class="nav-hasPanel nav-item" data-nav-panelkey="AndroidPanel" role="navigation" aria-label="Appstore for Android">                          
 <span class="nav-text">Appstore for Android</span>                          
 </span>
```

Here is my automation code:

```
@Test
public void departmentsDropMusic1() throws Exception {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-shopall']"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);


    WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-flyout-shopAll > div:nth-child(2)"));

    if (dropDown.isDisplayed()) {

        System.out.println("pass");
    } else {

        Assert.fail();
    }
    WebElement musicSubMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//span[contains(text(), 'Amazon Music')]"));


    action.moveToElement(musicSubMenu).build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
```

I have tried other xpaths as well, using the various labels provided in the html code, to no avail. WebDriver will only move to the first element (aria-label "Amazon Video"), and not the other elements listed.

Interestingly enough, when I use a for-loop to move through all of the items in the menu, there are no issues.

Comment: What is happening exactly? Any errors when you try mouse moving to the other menu items?

Comment: What i guess it, there are multiple elements with the same xpath. So selenium, by default mouse hovers to the first identified element with that xpath(usually top element in the DOM). We can use the index in the xpath to point out the particular occurance of the xpath.

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based HTML and code trials.

Comment: @DebanjanB -- thank you for letting me know and the article too. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is moving to first element in the dropdown as all elements of sub categories are loading when we move to first element in the list.

To overcome this, we need to move to the first element before moving to any other elements in the list. I have created one method to solve your issue. If you pass the sub menu name than it will move over on the sub menu.

The code is given below.

```
@Test
public void departmentsDropMusic1() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Projects\\SeleniumDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    openSubMenu("Amazon Music");

    openSubMenu("Fire TV");

}
```

The open sub menu method code is here,

```
public void openSubMenu(String menu) throws InterruptedException{


       //mouse over on Main menu 'Departments'
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-shopall']"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000L);

        //verify sub menus are listed or not
        WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-flyout-shopAll"));

        if (dropDown.isDisplayed()) {
            System.out.println("pass");

        } else {

            Assert.fail();
        }

        //
        WebElement subMenu1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-flyout-shopAll > div.nav-tpl-itemList>span:nth-child(1)"));
        WebElement subMenuWantedToOpen = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#nav-flyout-shopAll > div.nav-tpl-itemList>span[aria-label='"+menu.trim()+"']"));

        action.moveToElement(subMenu1).moveToElement(subMenuWantedToOpen).build().perform();

        Thread.sleep(5000L);

        WebElement subMenuCat = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav-subcats > div.nav-subcat[style='display: block;']"));

        if(subMenuCat.isDisplayed()){
            System.out.println(subMenuCat.getText());
        }

}
```

It is working fine for me. Check and let me know if any difficulties.

Comment: Wonderful, works great! Thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you are automating the large sites like amazon.com, please be sure that the element has no child node, when you try to inspect it through firebug, and some times it depends on the browser itself make sure you are using latest web browser version.

Comment: Thank you for your input!. I've been using the latest versions, still bummed out that the new Firefox, Developer Addition doesn't have the FirePath feature...